# Cordova XMLHttpRequest cross-domain request

Tags: javascript, mysql, xml, cordova

**Hi !**
I am trying to execute XMLHttpRequest to get information from mysql database.
I whitelisted the domain (containing the php file that create the XML outpout) inside config.xml file from cordova, but it does not work.
It Works well on the domain when code is fired from server but not from phone or simulator.
Here is my code :

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
else{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    for(var i=0; i < xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("place").length; i++) {
        var xmlName = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("name")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML += xmlName +"<br>"
    }
}
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://www.mywebsite.com/xmlcreate.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Thanks for helps !

Comment: What error messages do you get when you try to run it from the simulator?

Comment: What, exactly, have you put in the config.xml file?

Comment: @quentin simulator or phone does not shows error. page is loading with header and footer but fields i'm trying to fill still blank.

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.mycompanuy.myApp" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>AppName</name>
    <description>My description</description>
    <author email="dev@mycompany.com" href="http://www.mycompany.com">Me</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
 <access origin="*.googleapis.com"/>
 <access origin="*.gstatic.com"/>
 <access origin="*.mydomain.it" />
 <access origin="http://mydomain.it/*" />
 <access origin="http://www.mydomain.it/*" />
</widget>

Comment: In my xmlcreate.php (distant file taht generate xml) I put : header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); This works locally only with firefox : file:///C:/Apps/Comune/www/visits.html